# how to animat a QPixmap in qt?

Tags: qt, animation, qpixmap

if possible animated a QPixmap?in my program I have a QPixmap (image of super Mario).i want to animate it.i mean  it should go forward and jumping.it is hard for me to design shape of  super Mario again and prefer to use of image.

```
#ifndef MYQGRAPHICOBJECT_H
#define MYQGRAPHICOBJECT_H
#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
extern QPixmap super;
class MyQgraphicObject : public QGraphicsObject
{
Q_OBJECT
private:
 QPropertyAnimation* pro;
 QPixmap pi;
 public:
explicit MyQGraphicObject(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0,QPixmap p= super);
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
QRectF boundingRect()const;
signals:
public slots:   
};
#endif // MYQGRAPHICOBJECT_H
#include "myqgraphicobject.h"
#include <QGraphicsItem>
MyQGraphicObject::MyQGraphicObject(QGraphicsItem *parent, QPixmap p) :
QGraphicsObject(parent),pi(p)
{
 pro=new QPropertyAnimation();
}
QRectF MyQGraphicObject::boundingRect() const
{
}
```

Comment: You need multiple images, one for each animation frame. Then just change the pixmap at right times (by QTimer and/or by position I suppose) to achieve animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some code which does the same with sprite sheet.
Its explained [here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2010/07/sprite-animation-from-sprite-sheet-in.html)

Basically, you draw picture with size and location of sprite

```
mSpriteImage = new QPixmap(":dragon.png");
painter->drawPixmap ( mPos.x(),mPos.y(), *mSpriteImage, 
                                   mCurrentFrame, 0, 100,100 );
```

and on timer, you change the location of sprite.

```
void Sprite::nextFrame()
{
    //following variable keeps track which 
    //frame to show from sprite sheet
    mCurrentFrame += 100;
    if (mCurrentFrame >= 500 )
        mCurrentFrame = 0;
    mPos.setX( mPos.x() + 10 );
}
```